# Jackson, deserialize property based on another property (dependent property)

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using Jackson, is there a way to deserialize a proprty that depends on the value of another property?

if i have this json `{"foo":"a","bar":"b"}` i'd like to deserialize it to the Test class below as `Test [foo=a, bar=b_a]`, where bar is the value of the json property "bar" and the value of the property "foo".

Of course this is a trivial example, the real deal would be to deserialize a datamodel entity: `{"line":"C12", "machine": {"line":"C12", "code":"A"}}` machine.line and line are always the same, and i'd like to express it like this: `{"line":"C12", "machine": "A"}`

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

public abstract class Main{

    private static class Test {
        @JsonProperty
        private String foo;
        @JsonProperty
        @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
        private String bar;

        // ...other fields to be deserialized with default behaviour

        private Test() {
        }

        public Test(String a, String bar) {
            this.foo = a;
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Test [foo=" + foo + ", bar=" + bar + "]";
        }
    }

    private static class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {

        protected CustomDeserializer() {
            super(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            String foo = //how to get foo property?
            String value = p.getValueAsString();
            if (!foo.isEmpty()) {
                return value + "_" + foo;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Test foo2 = mapper.readValue("{\"foo\":\"a\",\"bar\":\"b\"}", Test.class);
        System.out.println(foo2); // Test [foo=a, bar=b_a]

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've resorted using `BeanDeserializerModifier`

Please notice that the following code is not fully functioning because it relies on code I'm not allowed to share, but it should suffice to get the idea.

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.TypeAnnotationsScanner;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.AssistedInject;

public class JsonDelegateDeserializerModule extends SimpleModule {
        
    // !! must be registered as guice factory
    public interface JsonDelegateDeserializerFactory {
        JsonDelegateDeserializerModule create(String packagePath);
    }

    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface JsonDelegateDeserializer {

        public Class<? extends StdDeserializer<?>> deserializer();

        public Class<?> forType();
    }

    protected interface JsonDeserializerFactory {
        // non metto nessun generic in TagHandler o guice non riesce piu a creare la
        // factory!
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public JsonDeserializer create(JsonDeserializer baseDeserializer);
    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonDelegateDeserializerModule.class);

    @Inject
    private FactoryInjector injector;

    private final String packagePath;

    @AssistedInject
    protected JsonDelegateDeserializerModule(@Assisted String packagePath) {
        super();
        this.packagePath = packagePath;
    }

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return JsonDelegateDeserializerModule.class.getSimpleName() + "[" + packagePath + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTypeId() {
        return JsonDelegateDeserializerModule.class.getSimpleName() + "[" + packagePath + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {

        Reflections reflectios = new Reflections(packagePath, new SubTypesScanner(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner());

        Map<Class<?>, JsonDeserializerFactory> classToDeserializerFactory = new HashMap<>();

        Set<Class<?>> classesWithModifier = reflectios.getTypesAnnotatedWith(JsonDelegateDeserializer.class);
        for (Class<?> classWithModifier : classesWithModifier) {
            JsonDelegateDeserializer annotation = classWithModifier.getAnnotation(JsonDelegateDeserializer.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                Class<? extends StdDeserializer<?>> deserializerType = annotation.deserializer();
                Class<?> forType = annotation.forType();
                try {
                    JsonDeserializerFactory factory = injector.getFactory(JsonDeserializerFactory.class,
                            deserializerType);
                    classToDeserializerFactory.put(forType, factory);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception was thown while creating deserializer {} for type {}:", deserializerType,
                            forType, e);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!classToDeserializerFactory.isEmpty()) {
            setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
                @Override
                public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                        JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
                    List<Class<?>> possibleTypesList = new LinkedList<>();

                    if (deserializer instanceof BeanDeserializer) {
                        for (Entry<Class<?>, JsonDeserializerFactory> entry : classToDeserializerFactory.entrySet()) {
                            Class<?> type = entry.getKey();
                            if (type.isAssignableFrom(deserializer.handledType())) {
                                possibleTypesList.add(type);
                            }
                        }

                        if (possibleTypesList.size() > 1) {
                            possibleTypesList.sort(new Comparator<Class<?>>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(Class<?> o1, Class<?> o2) {
                                    if (o1.isAssignableFrom(o2)) {
                                        return 1;
                                    } else {
                                        return -1;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        
                        Class<?> type = Utils.first(possibleTypesList);
                        if (type == null) {
                            return super.modifyDeserializer(config, beanDesc, deserializer);
                        } else {
                            JsonDeserializerFactory factory = classToDeserializerFactory.get(type);
                            JsonDeserializer<?> modifiedDeserializer = factory.create(deserializer);
                            return super.modifyDeserializer(config, beanDesc, modifiedDeserializer);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // è gia stato impostato un deserializzatore piu specifico, non imposato questo
                        return super.modifyDeserializer(config, beanDesc, deserializer);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        super.setupModule(context);
    }

}
```

then you can simply annotate the Mixin to add the custom deserializer

```
@JsonDelegateDeserializer(deserializer = LoadLineDeserializer.class, forType = Line.class)
public interface LineMixIn {

    public static class LoadLineDeserializer extends DelegatingDeserializer {
        @AssistedInject
        public LoadLineDeserializer(@Assisted JsonDeserializer baseDeserializer, LineService lineService) {
            super(baseDeserializer);
        }

        // ...
    }
    
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is specify a custom deserializer that involves your `Test` class instead of your string field because the deserialization of your property is based on the value of another property:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Test> {}

@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
public class Test {}
```

Then you can deserialize your object reading the [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) tree built from your input string:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Test> {

    @Override
    public Test deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String foo = node.get("foo").asText();
        String bar = node.get("bar").asText();
        if (!foo.isEmpty()) {
            bar = (bar + '_' + foo);
        }
        return new Test(foo, bar);
    }
    
}

//your example
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Test foo2 = mapper.readValue("{\"foo\":\"a\",\"bar\":\"b\"}", Test.class);
        System.out.println(foo2); // Test [foo=a, bar=b_a]
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, but this way I need to also manually deserialize all other fields. Is there a way to delegate that to the default serializer and only deal with bar?

Comment: @lelmarir Inside the custom deserializer you can iterate over all elements with [JsonNode.html#fields()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields()) and decide what to do with every element.

Comment: ok, but how do I delegate it to the default deserializer? Otherwise i need to know the field, deverialize it and call the right setter

Comment: @lelmarir In the case you presented you have to use only one custom deserializer like mine to solve your problem, the default deserializer is excluded.

Comment: of course there are other fields to be deserialized, that was just an example. I've updated the question

Comment: @lelmarir Ah I think I understand now what you mean. If you are agree probably the best thing is that you ask a new question with a new example because I should modify my code answer to adapt it to the new scenario and I want to be sure I understand well the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem today and I wanted to share my solution. So instead of using a `@JsonDeserialize`, I use a `@JsonCreator` on the parent object with a package private constructor to accept the "raw" properties and then I can process this data and return better objects.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        final var testData = "{\"foo\":\"a\",\"bar\":\"b\"}";
        final var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final var testObj = mapper.readValue(testData, Test.class);

        System.out.println(testObj); // Test[foo=a, bar=a_b]
    }

    record Test (
            String foo,
            String bar
    ){
        @JsonCreator Test(
                @JsonProperty("foo") String foo,
                @JsonProperty("bar") String bar,
                @JsonProperty("_dummy") String _dummy // extra param for the constructor overloading
        ) {
            this(foo, deserializeBar(foo, bar));
        }

        private static String deserializeBar(String foo, String bar) {
            if (foo == null || foo.isEmpty()) {
                return bar;
            }

            return "%s_%s".formatted(foo, bar);
        }
    }
}
```